# Extract subtitles from mp4 using ffmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg, mp4

I've been trying to extract subtitles from an mp4 file but I can't get the output format right.

I have reason to believe that this is an image based subtitle format.

What's the correct command the extract the subtitles so that I can view the subtitle images?

Thank you!

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can do it this way:

```
ffmpeg -i my_file.mp4 outfile.srt
```

Comment: ffmpeg, the video equivalent of the Swiss Army knife. Nice elegant solution.

Comment: I'm getting `Output file #0 does not contain any stream` while it contains two subtitle streams : `Stream #0:2[0x3](bre): Subtitle: dvd_subtitle (mp4s / 0x7334706D), 720x576, 6 kb/s (default)` and `Stream #0:3[0x4](fra): Subtitle: dvd_subtitle (mp4s / 0x7334706D), 720x576, 6 kb/s`.

Answer (score 0):

The OP asked to extract subpictures, not text subtitles.  The correct command to extract subpictures would be something like this:

```
ffmpeg -i src.m4v -c copy -map 0:2 dest.en.sup
```

Change the "2" in the parameters to -map to select the track with subpictures.

If you do have text subtitles (as opposed to subpictures) to extract, this will work:

```
ffmpeg -i src.m4v -c srt -map 0:2 dest.en.srt
```